# Possible values for PersonType in Microsoft Graph People API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to use the People API in a project which will differentiate the People based on the PersonType.e.g.External or internal people.
We couldn't find any documentation on all possible values of PersonType.
We have looked into the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/persontype?view=graph-rest-1.0

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for **Person:Organization** and/or **Other:Guest**.

I found it mentioned here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/people-api-available-in-microsoft-graph-v1/

"We have consolidated the personType, mailboxType and sources properties into one property called personType."

However, the values are not really just a combination of those values.

Class: **Person**

Subclasses:

- OrganizationUser: User in the signed-in user’s organization.
- PersonalContact: Contact added to the signed-in user’s address book.
- OrganizationContact:Contact added to the organization’s address book.
- ImplicitContact: Entity deemed relevant to the signed-in user based on communication, collaboration, or business signals.
- Unknown

Class: **Group**

Subclasses:

- UnifiedGroup: Azure Active Directory group, such as an Office 365 group
- ImplicitGroup: Entity group deemed relevant to the signed-in user based on communication, collaboration, or business signals.
- PublicDistributionList: Public contact list in the signed-in user’s organization.
- PersonalDistributionList: Contact list in the signed-in user’s address book.
- Unknown

Class: **Other**

Subclasses:

- Room: Room mailbox in the signed-in user’s organization.
- Guest: Azure Active Directory business-to-business (B2B) collaboration user.
- Unknown

Comment: Thanks for the help. Was searching it for days.